# DbMigrator Issues

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

I tried to register an account on the abp.io site to post about this but I keep getting an internal 500 server error. (Not a good sign when that's one of the intended uses of the framework).

I'm running through the Getting Started tutorial and the DbMigrator gives me the following error -

```
[14:14:30 INF] ABP CLI (https://abp.io)
[14:14:31 INF] Version 4.2.1 (Stable)
[14:14:31 ERR] Migrations failed: Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
System.Exception: Migrations failed: Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
   at Volo.Abp.Cli.Commands.CreateMigrationAndRunMigrator.ExecuteAsync(CommandLineArgs commandLineArgs) in D:\ci\Jenkins\workspace\abp-framework-release\abp\framework\src\Volo.Abp.Cli.Core\Volo\Abp\Cli\Commands\CreateMigrationAndRunMigrator.cs:line 37
   at Volo.Abp.Cli.CliService.RunAsync(String[] args) in D:\ci\Jenkins\workspace\abp-framework-release\abp\framework\src\Volo.Abp.Cli.Core\Volo\Abp\Cli\CliService.cs:line 59

C:\Test\src\Xams.DbMigrator\bin\Debug\net5.0\Xams.DbMigrator.exe (process 35324) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

I've verified the connection string is correct and working.

Comment: The error message has given the possible problem, you should try it.

Comment: Could you check your **\*.DbMigrations** folder? If there is not any **Migrations** folder inside of it, you can create a new migration by using **dotnet ef** tool => `dotnet ef migrations add "Initial Migration"`. After that when you run your DbMigrator project it should create the database.